# damaged rim - is a new need a new one?

Tags: wheels

My friends rim was damaged:

[image]

Should a new one be purchased?

Comment: There are companies that straighten wheels, compare the repair price to a new one or one from the junk yard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

minor damages can be no problem and some can be perfected by a mechanic. but this level of damage needs you to buy a new one.

Comment: Quite correct - replace it.

Comment: It's just a steel rim anyway. Could be fixed, but the cost to get it straightened and trued would cost as much or more than replacement ... especially if you picked one up from a wrecking yard or second hand.

Comment: Paul is correct. Isaac is a bit off. Mechanics don't usually waste time correcting steel rims. You'll have to go to a tire or a wheel shop. It has to be rounded or else your wheel will be jumpy.